# shell glob expansion with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, glob, sh

I'd like to write a Posix shell script function that will match on a pattern with both spaces and glob characters (*?) that need to be expanded.  In Python, *glob.glob('/tmp/hello world*')* will return the correct list.  How do I do this in the shell?

```
#!/bin/sh

## this function will list
## all of the files in the /tmp
## directory that match pattern
f() {
  PATTERN="$1"
  ls -1 "/tmp/$PATTERN"
}

touch '/tmp/hello world {1,2,3}.txt'
f 'hello world*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find`'s pattern matching is not exactly the same as the shell's, but it's pretty close, so you can take advantage of that:

```
f() {
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "$1" | sed 's#^.*/##'
}
```

(the `sed` command is there to remove the path prefix from the filename.)

Comment: You can ommit the sed command if you use `-printf %f\\n`. So something like  this should work: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "$PATTERN" -printf %f\\n`

Comment: @AlexanderSulfrian Unfortunately, not all versions of `find` support `-printf`, so that won't be portable.

Answer (score 6):

You can enclose everything except the `*` in quotes:

```
ls -l "hello world"*
ls -l "hello world"*".txt"
```

You can then pass a quoted string to `f()`. Using the string inside `f()` will require `eval`.

```
#!/bin/sh

## this function will list
## all of the files in the /tmp
## directory that match pattern
f() {
  PATTERN=$1
  eval ls -1 "/tmp/$PATTERN"
}

touch '/tmp/hello world {1,2,3}.txt'
f '"hello world"*'
```

Comment: I know that.  But I want to write a function or a script that takes a pattern as a argument.

Comment: I edited my answer with a version of your script that seems to work

Comment: Warning: `eval` can cause very bad behavior if the pattern contains the wrong shell metacharacters (like `'`, `<`, `>`, etc...)